# How to query in database to check if Phrase this character exist or not in groovy

Tags: mysql, grails, grails-orm

I am new in groovy.
I am trying to make query in database that if this character for example "099900" contain in database.
in general I save in database the string like : "9898989898"
but I want to make query that give me all result who's character begin with "98". Any idea?

```
class AccountNumber {


    static reportable = [columns: ['id', 'number']]

    static mapping = {
        cache false
        table 'accountNumber'
        version false
        id generator: 'identity', column: 'id'
    }
    Integer id;
    String number;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GRAILS way of doing it:

```groovy
def accounts = AccountNumber.findByNumberLike("98%")

// Now you can do something with the returned accounts
// For example:
accounts.each { account ->
    println "ID: ${account.id}, NUMBER: ${account.number}"
}
```

Comment: Here the official documentation about quering on [GRAILS 2](https://grails.github.io/grails2-doc/2.5.x/guide/GORM.html#querying) and [GRAILS 3 & 4](http://gorm.grails.org/6.1.x/hibernate/manual/#querying)

Answer (score 1):

In `MySQL` you can use `substring`.

```
select substring(column_name, 1, 2)='98'
```

> SUBSTRING :
> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring

I have no knowledge how to implement on groovy, but you can find very helpful information here: https://groovy-lang.org/databases.html